# How to fix DevCC compiler error: [Error] expected unqualified-id before 'if'?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm doing a homework problem right and need some help figuring out how to solve a compiler error: [Error] expected unqualified-id before 'if'.

I've tried including the functions in the int main function but that leads to more errors. I've tried looking for missing curly braces but can't seem to find any.

"if (surge != 'Y')" is where I'm getting [Error] expected unqualified-id before 'if'.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

double calcFare (double perMinute, double lengthMinutes, double minuteFare, double perMile, double distanceMiles, double mileFare, double baseFare, double totalFare, char carClass);
double calcFareSurge (double surgeFare, double perMinute, double lengthMinutes, double minuteFare, double perMile, double distanceMiles, double mileFare, double baseFare, double totalFare, double surgeMultiplier, char carClass);
double test;
void output (string name, double totalFare);

int main()
{
    string name;
    double surgeFare, perMinute, lengthMinutes, minuteFare, perMile, distanceMiles, mileFare, surgeMultiplier, baseFare, totalFare;
    char surge, carClass;

    cout << "Enter name: " << endl;
    getline(cin, name);
    cout << "Enter time in minutes: " << endl;
    cin >> lengthMinutes;
    cout << "Enter distance in miles: " << endl;
    cin >> distanceMiles;
    cout << "Enter 'X' for uberX or 'S' for SUV or 'L' for luxury: " << endl;
    cin >> carClass;
    carClass = (char) toupper(carClass);
    cout << "Enter 'Y' if surge or 'N' if not: " << endl;
    cin >> surge;
    surge = (char) toupper(surge);

    if (surge == 'Y')
    {
        cout << "Enter surge multiplier: " << endl;
        cin >> surgeMultiplier;
    }

    totalFare = calcFare(perMinute, lengthMinutes, minuteFare, perMile, distanceMiles, mileFare, baseFare, totalFare, carClass);

    output(name, totalFare);

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}

    if (surge != 'Y')
    {
        double calcFare (double perMinute, double lengthMinutes, double minuteFare, double perMile, double distanceMiles, double mileFare, double baseFare, double totalFare, char carClass)
        {       
            if (carClass == 'X')
            {       
                baseFare = 2.00;
                perMinute = 0.22;
                perMile = 1.15;
                minuteFare = perMinute * lengthMinutes;
                mileFare = perMile * distanceMiles;
                totalFare = minuteFare + mileFare + baseFare;
            }
            else if (carClass == 'S')
            {   
                baseFare = 15.00;
                perMinute = 0.90;
                perMile = 3.75;
                minuteFare = perMinute * lengthMinutes;
                mileFare = perMile * distanceMiles;
                totalFare = minuteFare + mileFare + baseFare;   
            }
            else if (carClass == 'L')
            {
                baseFare = 5.00;
                perMinute = 0.50;
                perMile = 2.75;
                minuteFare = perMinute * lengthMinutes;
                mileFare = perMile * distanceMiles;
                totalFare = minuteFare + mileFare + baseFare;
            }   
        }
    else
    {
        double calcFareSurge (double surgeFare, double perMinute, double lengthMinutes, double minuteFare, double perMile, double distanceMiles, double mileFare, double baseFare, double totalFare, double surgeMultiplier, char carClass)
        {
            if (carClass == 'X')
            {   
                baseFare = 2.00;
                perMinute = 0.22;
                perMile = 1.15;
                surgeFare = baseFare * surgeMultiplier;
                minuteFare = perMinute * lengthMinutes;
                mileFare = perMile * distanceMiles;
                totalFare = minuteFare + mileFare + baseFare;
            }
            else if (carClass == 'S')
            {   
                baseFare = 15.00;
                perMinute = 0.90;
                perMile = 3.75;
                surgeFare = baseFare * surgeMultiplier;
                minuteFare = perMinute * lengthMinutes;
                mileFare = perMile * distanceMiles;
                totalFare = minuteFare + mileFare + baseFare;
            }
            else if (carClass == 'L')
            {
                baseFare = 5.00;
                perMinute = 0.50;
                perMile = 2.75;
                surgeFare = baseFare * surgeMultiplier;
                minuteFare = perMinute * lengthMinutes;
                mileFare = perMile * distanceMiles;
                totalFare = minuteFare + mileFare + baseFare;
            }
        }
    }

    void output(string name, double totalFare)     
    {
        cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;
        cout << "Rider's name: " << name << endl;
        cout << "Total: $ " << totalFare << endl;
        return;
    }
```

Comment: `if (surge != 'Y')` is outside of any function.  Statements are not allowed outside of functions.

Comment: `toupper` is in the header `<cctype>`. You should include `<cctype>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (surge != 'Y')
    {.........
     .......
}
```

The above mentioned code segment needs to be put in a separate function or inside main ().

(a) In case you are moving this to inside the main function you will still get another error as you have defined double calcFare(),inside both if and else ,you can only make a function call from inside of if -else ,not a function definition ,in both cases you will have to define the function outside of if and else.

(b) You can create  a new function and have handle the cases accordingly .

---

Suggested Reading

(-) Difference between Function call and Function definition.

(-) Return a value from a function call

Hope this helps